# Bus location schema design in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am developing a bus ticket booking app in node.js.
I want to design a location schema in such a way that whenever user enters a from-location like: philadelphia then in the to-location dropdown all the other location should appear like new jersy or newyork **except** *philadelphia*.

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location:{
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      subLocation: [String],
      //Should I add type = 1
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what does `all the other location should appear like new jersy or newyork except philadelphia.`. mean? Is there any deciding factor like nearby cities, famous cities or already entered cities by user? Any sort of relationship or just random?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara When a user wants to go somewhere he selects two locations like from-location and to-location. eg. like I want to go from mumbai to bangalore. Mumbai is a from-location and bangalore is a to location. I enter Mumbai from the dropdown of from-location and there is is an empty to-location right now but whenever I click on to-location I should not see Mumbai in the to-location dropdown because eventually I will not go from mumbai to mumbai I will go from mumbai to ratlam, mumbai to nagpur or mumbai to bangalore

Comment: Yes nearby cities but not that particular city from where user is boarding

Comment: Ok, my question was how did you get those cities are they already in DB and how do these to-locations come in? Because tomorrow, if you add new york in your DB and select from-location as Mumbai and new york, will come as a to-location that is not a viable location. So, you might need to re-think about the logic.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it and I do not have any solution as well. Do you have any idea how to do that. That is where I am stuck right now

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara

Comment: What API you will be using to get bus routes? Are you creating your own? Or will you use Google APIs? I think that will be a better solution. I would recommend using only the top destination that users accept as to should be shown as there will be a multitude of options b/w from and to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245180/discussion-between-hrishikesh-pathak-and-apoorva-chikara).

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB $ne (not equal to) method

```
 db.collection.find({
  "location.name": {
    $ne: req.body.fromLocation //change variable name according to requirement
  }
})
```

Now you can set this data in the other dropdown

Here is a working [mongoplayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LWgX0gYUr2H)

Comment: can I use req.body.from instead of philadelphia

Comment: of course, I wrote it directly just for example. Updated the answer for better explanation